# How can I present bigquery results in a website?

Tags: wordpress, google-bigquery

I have a big query table (about 4.5Gb, 7+ millions lines) and would like to present it with a searcheable field in a website page.
Any ideas? Or... is it big query the tool meant to do that?

Answer (score 7):

BigQuery is not designed to present your data out to the world on a website directly. To do this you would use another tool, and there are many to choose from.

For a start, consider how your data will be published to the web - being a pretty big table, you are unlikely to serve this up as one big chunk, it would be better to build an API interface where users can request chunks of data by firing requests at where the data is stored - this would also be cheaper for you both computationally and financially (imagine if every user was loading ALL the data every time they viewed your site!).

Secondly, consider where you store it. If you are serving data up to the web you may or may not wish for it to remain in BigQuery. Another approach would be to move the selected data to another database, such as [MySQL](https://www.mysql.com/), then connect this to your website using one of many options (PHP, [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) etc.).

A third option which may suit, depending on the complexity of your data, is building a [Dash app](https://dash.plot.ly) in python and publishing this to the web, so users can interact with the data through a dashboard.

None of these options are trivial, it's quite complex to serve up such a large amount of data on a website, so all approaches will take some further research and considerable work.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ben-p! Really helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Another option is Google Data Studio. Data Studio is the Google Cloud Platform Business Intelligence tool.  You can connect a BigQuery data set to DataStudio and build a dashboard with filters, custom metrics, etc...  You can then publish and share that dashboard to stakeholders.  The share rights operate just like google docs, sheets, slides etc...

Something to keep in mind is that DataStudio performs SQL queries behind the scenes on your BigQuery data set.  This means you are charged for each visualization that is rendered so make sure you are aware of your report query costs.  A way to manage this is to create aggregated tables and connect those to DataStudio.

Good Luck! Data Studio is a great tool!

Comment: Thanks @brettrospective! I've made a few tests with GDS. Great tool! I want to keep my project costs as low as possible for now. So I'll leave BigQuery for a while serving only converted Excel files and perhaps providing paid data analysis using GSD as a backing tool. Have a good one!